# Is there a way to disable webpack's default output when a module build fails?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm struggling to find a way to disable webpack from outputting something like this when it comes across a SyntaxError.

```
throw new Error("Module build failed: SyntaxError: ...)
```

Ideally I would like it to output nothing instead of a `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

I think webpack's bail option might be what you are looking for.  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#bail  Bail will stop at the first sign of an error instead of tolerating the error.